# How to speed up grep/awk command?

Tags: linux, performance, awk, grep

I am going to process the text file (>300 GB) and split it into small text files (~1 GB). I want to speed up grep/awk commands.

I need to grep the line which has values on column b, here are my ways:

```
# method 1:
awk -F',' '$2 ~ /a/ { print }' input

# method 2:
grep -e ".a" < inpuy
```

Both of ways cost 1min for each file. So how can I speed up this operation?

---

Sample of input file:

```
a,b,c,d
1,4a337485,2,54
4,2a4645647,4,56
6,5a3489556,3,22
9,,3,12
10,0,34,45
24,4a83944,3,22
45,,435,34
```

Expected output file:

```
a,b,c,d
1,4a337485,2,54
4,2a4645647,4,56
6,5a3489556,3,22
24,4a83944,3,22
```

Comment: Can other columns be empty? if not `fgrep -v ',,' input` should give slightly better performances than `grep -e`.

Comment: Dumb question... Why are you using the shell? If performance is a concern due to big data, why not write the optimized C program? (I assume you will be doing this more than once).

Comment: Where is the data coming from? How do you get it? What actual data does these huge files contain? How did you run your benchmarks? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56334265/edit) your question to improve it (which I voted to close, since too broad and unclear)

Comment: @infaak, IMHO, on first place you should have a log rotate mechanism so that you don't have huge size files in your box(unless it is a data file and you have a user data in it, which I doubt), it will really save you any other space issues unnecessary issues too.

Comment: You mention you want to process a 300GB file and split it into smaller files. The question you are asking seems to be part of a bigger program which would accommodate the split. If this is true, I am convinced that with a single awk, we can split the 300GB into smaller files with a single read. We would, however, need to understand the conditions for this.

Comment: When you say `cost 1min for each file` - do you mean for each input file or for each output file? If the latter, how do you know given 1 call to 1 tool should be producing all of your output files at 1 time? I feel like you're probably calling awk (or grep) in a loop and THAT is your problem rather than how fast the awk command is executing. Also, if you care about performance then that implies this is something you have to do repeatedly - you might want to fix whatever is generating these huge files instead of putting a band-aid on afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

> How to speed up grep/awk command?

Are you so sure that `grep` or `awk` is the culprit of your perceived slowness ? Do you know about [cut(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) or [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) ? Have you benchmarked the time to run [wc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) on your data? Probably the textual I/O is taking a lot of time.

Please benchmark *several* times, and use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) to benchmark your program.

I have a high-end Debian desktop (with a AMD 2970WX, 64Gb RAM, 1Tbyte SSD system disk, multi-terabyte 7200RPM SATA data disks) and just running `wc` on a 25Gbyte file (some `*.tar.xz` archive) sitting on a hard disk takes more than 10 minutes (measured with `time`), and `wc` is doing some *really simple textual* processing by reading that file *sequentially* so should run faster than `grep` (but, to my surprise, does not!) or `awk` on the *same* data :

```
wc /big/basile/backup.tar.xz  640.14s user 4.58s system 99% cpu 10:49.92 total
```

and (using `grep` on the *same* file to count occurrences of `a`)

```
grep -c a /big/basile/backup.tar.xz  38.30s user 7.60s system 33% cpu 2:17.06 total
```

### general answer to your question:

Just **write *cleverly*** (with efficient *O(log n)* [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure): [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), or [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), etc ...) **an equivalent program in C or C++ or Ocaml or most other good language and implementation**. Or buy more RAM to increase your [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). Or buy an [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) to hold your data. And **repeat your benchmarks more than once** (because of the page cache).

### suggestion for your problem : use a relational database

It is likely that using a plain textual file of 300Gb is *not* the best approach. **Having huge textual files is *usually* wrong** and is likely to be wrong once you need to process *several times* the same data. You'll better [pre-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_pre-processing) it somehow..

If you repeat the *same* `grep` search or `awk` execution on the *same* data file more than once, **consider instead using [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/index.html)** (see *also* [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/332071/40065) answer) or even some [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) real [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) (e.g. with [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) or some other good RDBMS) to store then process your original data.

So a possible approach (if you have enough disk space) might be to write some program (in C, Python, Ocaml etc...), fed by your original data, and filling some `sqlite` database. Be sure to have clever [database indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) and take time to *design* a good enough [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema), being aware of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: This is past your valid point but that `wc` time looked so dreadful I just had to see it myself. I had a 9 GB json file for which `time wc` produced `real    2m51.558s` which is in line with your observation. However, `time mawk '{nf+=NF;l+=length()+1}END{printf "%d %d %.0f", NR,nf,l}'` produced `real    1m0.348s` which was kind of surprising as I would've expected `wc` being a special purpose tool to outrun mawk.

Answer (score 2):

Use mawk, <s>avoid regex and do:</s>

```
$ mawk -F, '$2!=""' file
a,b,c,d
1,4a337485,2,54
4,2a4645647,4,56
6,5a3489556,3,22
10,0,34,45
24,4a83944,3,22
```

Let us know how long that took.

I did some tests with 10M records of your data, based on the results: use mawk and regex:

GNU awk and regex:

```
$ time gawk -F, '$2~/a/' file > /dev/null

real    0m7.494s
user    0m7.440s
sys     0m0.052s
```

GNU awk and no regex:

```
$ time gawk -F, '$2!=""' file >/dev/null

real    0m9.330s
user    0m9.276s
sys     0m0.052s
```

mawk and no regex:

```
$ time mawk -F, '$2!=""' file >/dev/null

real    0m4.961s
user    0m4.904s
sys     0m0.060s
```

mawk and regex:

```
$ time mawk -F, '$2~/a/' file > /dev/null

real    0m3.672s
user    0m3.600s
sys     0m0.068s
```

Comment: Oh, your definition of _has values on column b_ is different from mine (notice your header line, though). `mawk -F, '$2!="" && $2!=0' file` will fix it for this input but if you want only records where b field has `a` in it, use: `mawk -F, '$2~/a/` file`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your real problem is that you're calling awk repeatedly (probably in a loop), once per set of values of $2 and generating an output file each time, e.g.:

```
awk -F, '$2==""' input > novals
awk -F, '$2!=""' input > yesvals
etc.
```

Don't do that as it's very inefficient since it's reading the whole file on every iteration. Do this instead:

```
awk '{out=($2=="" ? "novals" : "yesvals")} {print > out}' input
```

That will create all of your output files with one call to awk. Once you get past about 15 output files it would require GNU awk for internal handling of open file descriptors or you need to add `close(out)`s when $2 changes and use `>>` instead of `>`:

```
awk '$2!=prev{close(out); out=($2=="" ? "novals" : "yesvals"); prev=$2} {print >> out}' input
```

and that would be more efficient if you sorted your input file first with (requires GNU sort for `-s` for stable sort if you care about preserving input ordering for the unique $2 values):

```
sort -t, -k2,2 -s
```